# Add an unpublished assets dialog to an AEM workflow

Tags: workflow, aem, aem-6

When publishing pages through an AEM(6.1) workflow, is it possible to add a dialog to show unpublished references in the same style as the standard publish process?

i.e. similar to https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/publishing-pages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the referenced assets with [AssetReferenceSearch](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/commons/util/AssetReferenceSearch.html)

```
AssetReferenceSearch assetReferenceSearch = new AssetReferenceSearch(pageContentNode, "/content/dam", resourceResolver);
Map<String, Asset> referencedAssets = assetReferenceSearch.search();
for (Map.Entry<String, Asset> entry : referencedAssets.entrySet()) {
        replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, entry.getValue().getPath());
}
```

Here I am replicating the Assets, but you could feed them into another workflow step for the author to approve.

Comment: Ah thanks, that gave me a bit to think about.
One thing though, I was unable to access the 'cq:lastReplicationAction' property that is at the jcr:content level of the acces, which is pretty usefull information on an asset.
Also I'm still at a loss as how to get the information to appear on screen as part of the workflow.  Currently I'm using an email notification for this.

Comment: Hey @enkor did you solve this issue? I need to add the same asset screen approval in the workflow.